# R: Keeping the 5 Biggest Rows in a Table

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I created some random data and then wrote the following program which loops through a series of data manipulation steps:

```
#load library
    library(dplyr)

library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)


####
results_table <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:10 ) {
    
    #generate random numbers
    random_1 =  runif(1, 80, 120)
    random_2 =  runif(1, random_1, 120)
    random_3 =  runif(1, 85, 120)
    random_4 =  runif(1, random_3, 120)
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    
    #calculate 60th quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    
    #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                   group_by(cat) %>%
                                   summarize(
                                       mean = mean(diff)
                                   ))
    
    #add "total mean" to this table
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))
    
    #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
    final_table_2$random_1 = random_1
    
    final_table_2$random_2 = random_2
    
    final_table_2$random_3 = random_3
    
    final_table_2$random_4 = random_4
    
    final_table_2$split_1 = split_1
    
    final_table_2$split_2 = split_2
    
    final_table_2$split_3 = split_3
    
    final_table_2$iteration_number = i
    
    
    results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)
    
    final_results = dcast(setDT(results_table), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')
    
}
```

After running this loop 10 times, the results ("final_results") looks like this:

```
final_results

    iteration_number  random_1  random_2  random_3  random_4    split_1   split_2   split_3          a         b         c total
 1:                1  95.67371 111.81329  94.00313 102.05692 0.84045638 0.6882731 0.7749321 0.82051282 0.6870229 0.7734554 0.730
 2:                2  92.31360 110.07617 106.46871 109.53428 0.24615922 0.8777580 0.7847697 0.24731183 0.8777429 0.7840909 0.744
 3:                3  81.02645 110.46446 116.42006 119.61718 0.11943576 0.9762721 0.9100522 0.14285714 0.9758162 0.9103448 0.943
 4:                4  90.35986 116.70888 114.15588 116.72312 0.07675141 0.8661540 0.3236617 0.08139535 0.8658065 0.3207547 0.702
 5:                5  89.28374 114.71034 119.70448 119.77249 0.08881443 0.6351936 0.8565509 0.09027778 0.6349614 0.8461538 0.573
 6:                6  87.35767 103.85755  97.44462 116.04144 0.48372890 0.2319129 0.2701634 0.47368421 0.2326333 0.2711370 0.255
 7:                7 112.91974 113.10267  99.20739 111.60051 0.52873965 0.6825709 0.5078129 0.52849741 0.6830709 0.5094340 0.605
 8:                8 102.17487 117.17008  95.93786  96.80284 0.81599406 0.7785768 0.8593795 0.81300813 0.7795276 0.8586667 0.843
 9:                9  82.62877  82.95787 105.70883 118.13665 0.44629189 0.0375750 0.4102906 0.44117647 0.1666667 0.4083333 0.408
10:               10  94.60865 106.70978  89.67872 104.21645 0.26431269 0.4899329 0.9060612 0.40000000 0.4897959 0.8992629 0.656
```

I am trying to modify the loop so that during the iterations, the table will only keep the 5 biggest results (based on the values of "final_results$total") at any time. This is to prevent the final table ("final_results") from getting too big.

After the loop is completed, I know how to "trim" the "final_results" table so that it only keeps the 5 biggest rows (in terms of "final_results$total"):

```
#sort the final table according to the desired criteria 
sorted_table = final_results[order(final_results$total, decreasing = TRUE),]  

#extract 5 biggest rows 
 sorted_table = sorted_table[1:5,]

#view the results
 head(sorted_table)
   iteration_number  random_1 random_2  random_3  random_4    split_1   split_2   split_3          a         b         c total
1:                3  81.02645 110.4645 116.42006 119.61718 0.11943576 0.9762721 0.9100522 0.14285714 0.9758162 0.9103448 0.943
2:                8 102.17487 117.1701  95.93786  96.80284 0.81599406 0.7785768 0.8593795 0.81300813 0.7795276 0.8586667 0.843
3:                2  92.31360 110.0762 106.46871 109.53428 0.24615922 0.8777580 0.7847697 0.24731183 0.8777429 0.7840909 0.744
4:                1  95.67371 111.8133  94.00313 102.05692 0.84045638 0.6882731 0.7749321 0.82051282 0.6870229 0.7734554 0.730
5:                4  90.35986 116.7089 114.15588 116.72312 0.07675141 0.8661540 0.3236617 0.08139535 0.8658065 0.3207547 0.702
```

**My question** : But is it possible to re-write the loop so that at any time, the table only contains 5 rows?  If I were to run this loop 1,000,000 times, the table would grow very large and I would like to trim it in advance.

E.g.

1. iterate the loop 5 times
2. for the 6th iteration, see if the value of "total" is smaller than any of the the previous 5 values of "total"

- if yes, discard the results from this iteration and go to the 7th iteration.
- if no, keep the results from this iteration, discard the row belonging to smallest iteration and go to the 7th iteration

3. repeat step 2) until you have iterated the loop 1,000,000 times.

Is it possible to add this step in the loop and trim the table as it is being created? Or is it only possible to trim the table after the entire loop has been completed?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add this line at the end `final_results <- head(final_results[order(-total)], 5)`

Comment: @akrun: thank you for your answer! this works perfectly! my only question: will adding this line of code speed up the code, since the final list never grows beyond 5 rows?

Comment: You may have to check with `microbenchmark` or `system.time`

Comment: @akrun: thank you for your reply. Maybe this line can also be added? 3rd last line: results_table <- head(results_table[order(-mean)], 5)

Comment: That will be before the `dcast`.  so, there will be less rows to dcast and should increase the speed

Comment: can both lines be added? results_table <- head(results_table[order(-mean)], 5) AND final_results <- head(final_results[order(-total)], 5) ?

Comment: I guess you can, but check if that results make sense for you after the dcast

Comment: @akrun: maybe it's better to remove that line you just added - I don't think the logic is correct.  i will post a new question

Comment: ok, I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the line

```
final_results <- head(final_results[order(-total)], 5)
```

at the end of the loop to only return the top 5 'total' rows

```
for (i in 1:10 ) {
    
    #generate random numbers
    random_1 =  runif(1, 80, 120)
    random_2 =  runif(1, random_1, 120)
    random_3 =  runif(1, 85, 120)
    random_4 =  runif(1, random_3, 120)
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    
    #calculate 60th quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    
    #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                   group_by(cat) %>%
                                   summarize(
                                       mean = mean(diff)
                                   ))
    
    #add "total mean" to this table
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))
    
    #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
    final_table_2$random_1 = random_1
    
    final_table_2$random_2 = random_2
    
    final_table_2$random_3 = random_3
    
    final_table_2$random_4 = random_4
    
    final_table_2$split_1 = split_1
    
    final_table_2$split_2 = split_2
    
    final_table_2$split_3 = split_3
    
    final_table_2$iteration_number = i
    
    
    results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)
   
    
    final_results = dcast(setDT(results_table), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')
    final_results <- head(final_results[order(-total)], 5)
    
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I posted a new question where I try to explain another problem I am experiencing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262017/r-function-only-produces-1-row-of-data