# R: Function only Produces 1 Row of Data

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am working with R. From a previous post ([R: Keeping the 5 Biggest Rows in a Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68260085/r-keeping-the-5-biggest-rows-in-a-table)), I generated some random data and wrote the following code which loops through a series of data manipulation steps and produces a table containing the results ("final_results"):

```
#load library
    library(dplyr)

library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)


####
results_table <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:10 ) {
    
    #generate random numbers
    random_1 =  runif(1, 80, 120)
    random_2 =  runif(1, random_1, 120)
    random_3 =  runif(1, 85, 120)
    random_4 =  runif(1, random_3, 120)
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    
    #calculate 60th quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    
    #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                   group_by(cat) %>%
                                   summarize(
                                       mean = mean(diff)
                                   ))
    
    #add "total mean" to this table
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))
    
    #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
    final_table_2$random_1 = random_1
    
    final_table_2$random_2 = random_2
    
    final_table_2$random_3 = random_3
    
    final_table_2$random_4 = random_4
    
    final_table_2$split_1 = split_1
    
    final_table_2$split_2 = split_2
    
    final_table_2$split_3 = split_3
    
    final_table_2$iteration_number = i
    
    
    results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)
   
    
    final_results = dcast(setDT(results_table), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')

#keep the 5 biggest results (according to the "total" variable)
    final_results <- head(final_results[order(-total)], 5)
    
}

#view output (should only have 5 rows)

final_results

   iteration_number  random_1 random_2  random_3  random_4    split_1   split_2   split_3          a         b         c total
1:                3  81.02645 110.4645 116.42006 119.61718 0.11943576 0.9762721 0.9100522 0.14285714 0.9758162 0.9103448 0.943
2:                8 102.17487 117.1701  95.93786  96.80284 0.81599406 0.7785768 0.8593795 0.81300813 0.7795276 0.8586667 0.843
3:                2  92.31360 110.0762 106.46871 109.53428 0.24615922 0.8777580 0.7847697 0.24731183 0.8777429 0.7840909 0.744
4:                1  95.67371 111.8133  94.00313 102.05692 0.84045638 0.6882731 0.7749321 0.82051282 0.6870229 0.7734554 0.730
5:                4  90.35986 116.7089 114.15588 116.72312 0.07675141 0.8661540 0.3236617 0.08139535 0.8658065 0.3207547 0.702
```

**Problem :** Now, I am trying to re-write the loop so that over the course of the loop:

- for each unique iteration:
- the "results_table" only keeps the rows corresponding to those iterations with the 5 largest value of "total mean"

E.g.

[image]

**Goal:** For the "results_table" shown above, each "black box" represents a set of iterations, and each "red box" shows the value of the "total mean". To prevent the "results_table" from growing in size with each iteration, I would only like to keep rows corresponding to the 5 biggest values (in this example indicated with the red boxes).

I tried to combine "results_table" and "final_table" into a single step using the following code:

```
#load library
library(dplyr)

library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)


####
results_table <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:10 ) {
    
    #generate random numbers
    random_1 =  runif(1, 80, 120)
    random_2 =  runif(1, random_1, 120)
    random_3 =  runif(1, 85, 120)
    random_4 =  runif(1, random_3, 120)
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    
    #calculate 60th quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    
    #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                   group_by(cat) %>%
                                   summarize(
                                       mean = mean(diff)
                                   ))
    
    #add "total mean" to this table
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))
    
    #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
    final_table_2$random_1 = random_1
    
    final_table_2$random_2 = random_2
    
    final_table_2$random_3 = random_3
    
    final_table_2$random_4 = random_4
    
    final_table_2$split_1 = split_1
    
    final_table_2$split_2 = split_2
    
    final_table_2$split_3 = split_3
    
    final_table_2$iteration_number = i
    
    
    results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)
    
    
    results_table = dcast(setDT(results_table), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')
    
    #keep the 5 biggest results (according to the "total" variable)
    results_table <- head(results_table[order(-total)], 5)
    
}

#view output (should only have 5 rows)

results_table
```

But this results in an error and outputs a table with only one row:

```
Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
  Item 2 has 10 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 12 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.

 #view output (should only have 5 rows)

  results_table
 
  iteration_number random_1 random_2 random_3 random_4   split_1   split_2   split_3         a         b         c total
1:                1 95.67371 111.8133 94.00313 102.0569 0.8404564 0.6882731 0.7749321 0.8205128 0.6870229 0.7734554  0.73
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?

Thanks

EDIT

@Ronak Shah: Is this what you meant?

```
#load library
    library(dplyr)

library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)

results_table <- vector('list', 10) 
####


for (i in 1:10 ) {
    
    #generate random numbers
    random_1 =  runif(1, 80, 120)
    random_2 =  runif(1, random_1, 120)
    random_3 =  runif(1, 85, 120)
    random_4 =  runif(1, random_3, 120)
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    
    #calculate 60th quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    
    #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                   group_by(cat) %>%
                                   summarize(
                                       mean = mean(diff)
                                   ))
    
    #add "total mean" to this table
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))
    
    #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
    final_table_2$random_1 = random_1
    
    final_table_2$random_2 = random_2
    
    final_table_2$random_3 = random_3
    
    final_table_2$random_4 = random_4
    
    final_table_2$split_1 = split_1
    
    final_table_2$split_2 = split_2
    
    final_table_2$split_3 = split_3
    
    final_table_2$iteration_number = i
    
    
    results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)
   
    
    results_table[[i]] <- final_table_2


    
}
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(cat = c("a", "b",  : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 8 

#view output (should only have 5 rows)
res <- bind_rows(results_table)
final <- dcast(setDT(res), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + 
               random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')

Error in dcast.data.table(setDT(res), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 +  : 
  Columns specified in formula can not be of type list
In addition: Warning message:
In setDT(res) :
  Some columns are a multi-column type (such as a matrix column): [1]. setDT will retain these columns as-is but subsequent operations like grouping and joining may fail. Please consider as.data.table() instead which will create a new column for each embedded column.

#view final result
final

Error: object 'final' not found
```

Comment: that error could be corrected with `fill = TRUE` in `rbindlist`

Comment: @akrun: thank you for your reply! I was a bit confused about that - in my original code, I did not even use the "rbindlist" command. Why is it telling me that there is an error involving "rbindlist"? thanks!

Comment: `results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2, fill = TRUE)`   It is the `rbind` as the object is a data.table

Comment: @akrun: I changed "rbind" to "rbindlist":  results_table <- rbindlist(results_table, final_table_2, fill=TRUE) .... but now I get the following error: Error in rbindlist(results_table, final_table_2, fill = TRUE) : 
  Input is data.frame but should be a plain list of items to be stacked .

Comment: You are converting the data.frame to data.table in `setDT(results_table)` thus it uses `rbind.data.table` which include `fill = TRUE`.  check `methods("rbind")
[1] rbind.data.frame  rbind.data.table* rbind.grouped_df* ...`

Comment: @akrun: thank you! i will keep working on it...

Comment: If you do not have indices on theLHS of assignments in for-loops you will be overwriting all but the last values of those named objects.

Comment: @thank you! I am still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initialising `results_table` as empty dataframe you can initialise it as list.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

results_table <- vector('list', 10)
```

From the `for` loop Remove the `dcast` line  and save the `final_table_2` in the list.

```
....
....
results_table[[i]] <- final_table_2

} #for loop end
```

After the loop you can combine the result and do the reshaping with `dcast`.

```
res <- bind_rows(results_table)
final <- dcast(setDT(res), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + 
               random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it and I got an error - I posted my understanding of your answer in an edit on my question. If you have time, can you please take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: @stats555 Remove this line as well. `results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)`. Sorry, I did not made it clear in my post.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think this will make the code easier to run for the computer?

Comment: I think so because 1) we are not increasing the object in a loop, we are using `list` now. 2) Also we are using `dcast` only once so that should help as well.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help! if you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68264265/how-to-define-fitness-functions-in-r